# Reversible folding function?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I have a set of numbers (generated as numeric strings) of variable size and I would like to store them in a hash table having both as key and value unsigned 32-bits integer. Of course the keys and values to hash can be larger (even larger than 64 bits), so before inserting them I need to do some sort of folding to reduce their size. However, I am not aware of any reversible way to fold keys - I thought about hashing, but this is usually not reversible. What are easy functions to use to transform a long string into a shorter one and the opposite way around in order to retrieve the original value?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to map _2n_ values to _n_ values in a reversible way?

Comment: you cannot. (unless maybe if you have specific input range)

Comment: Let's assume I can allow collisions to happen, since the probability is anyway extremely low and tolerable (and this is not really a real-life use case, I am just benchmarking the time required to do such a thing). Would that help finding a reversible function to fold?

Comment: Ask yourself how you would represent 1~4 with one bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** to map 64-bit values into 32-bit values in a reversible way. There are only 4294967296 possible 32-bit values, but you could have 429496729**7** different 64-bit values in your table. Then, two of them would have to be the same (this is called the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)) and that same value would have to map to two different 64-bit values when you reversed it.